# NSData loading UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsdata

How to tell if the NSData returns nil if theres no internet connection or if the image is no longer available  ??

this is the code:

```
NSString *str = @"http://p.twimg.com/A76-I-PCYAA75YH.jpg";//URL is broken
NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
```

The nsdata is nil in two cases:

1. If thers no internet connection.
2. Or if the image in the url is no longer available.

Comment: Use [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:)

Comment: Surely it's as easy as checking imgData==nil...? You must be really asking something more. Do you need to re-phrase your question?

Comment: no tod, I know how to check if the object is nil or not, the problem is that I want to know why is it nil, is it because theres no connection or is it because the image is no longer available

Comment: Use the method @nhahtdh linked to and check the error parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code.

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://imageAddress.com"];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
    queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
    completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
        NSData * data,
        NSError * error) {
if (!error){
        NSImage* image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    // do whatever you want with image
}

}];
```

Comment: If there is an error the reason will be in the error parameter and you can take an appropriate action.

Comment: this is the answer :) ,, I made some edit to make it work,, I'll update your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should first test for an available network data connection separately, see Apple's [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code.

Then, if you have a network connection, you can go ahead and try and load the file.  If it then fails, you know it's not because there was no network data connection.

Comment: I was going for this approach but I'm loading about 100 images, is it necessary to check each time I load an image ? plus what if the connection fails after check and while downloading??

Comment: If you are worried about the checking overhead just check the network connection on a failure to determine the reason. Or use an `NSURLConnection` method like `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` and check the error to determine the failure. Loading an image from the Internet on the main thread is a bad idea anyway. See the answer by @Vinu1991.

Answer (score 0):

Before  downloading check for internet connection and then download. You can check availaibility bu putting condition of

```
if(imgdata == nil)
     // image is not available in server
  else 
        // convert data into image and use
         image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
```